# WordPress - Added action to a hook disappears in list of callbacks

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook, action, buddypress

Encountered a very frustrating bug after many hours of debugging through xDebug. A function that was added to a hook through add_action is missing or inaccessible when do_action is fired from within a plugin(BuddyPress).

The function I am referring to in my theme folder: UpdateSalesForceAvatar

Action: 'bp_members_avatar_uploaded'

Theme code where add_action for the above function is added:

```
       public static function RegisterActions(): void {
            add_action( 'xprofile_data_after_save', [self::class, 'UpdateSalesforce'] );
            add_action( 'xprofile_data_after_delete', [self::class, 'UpdateSalesforce'] );
            add_action( 'bp_members_avatar_uploaded', [self::class, 'UpdateSalesForceAvatar'], 10, 3);
            add_filter( 'bp_core_avatar_folder_dir', [self::class, 'HandleAvatarFolderDir']);

        }
```

Function prototype for UpdateSalesForceAvatar:

```
public static function UpdateSalesForceAvatar($item_id, $type, $avatar_data) {
```

Here are the screenshots and debug information that will hopefully allow someone to help me understand why it is missing when the global $wp_filters is accessed from the plugin.

1st screenshot after add_action

[image: After add_action]

2nd screenshot after future execution of code within BuddyPress
[image: Call from within Buddypress plugin(web/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-core/bp-core-avatars.php Line 1255]

Any and all feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Going to search for remove_all_actions() calls within the theme and attached plugins

Comment: Nope that wasn't it. Going to move the add-action to functions.php instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you have to try another location, potentially because of plugins interacting with that action.

The solution was more of a workaround, moved the registration of the action instead to functions.php